# Google Play email re. call/sms log permissions?

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I have ~a dozen apps on the play store which are identical, with UI tweaks for various clients.  I've recently gotten an automated email from Google Play for 2 of my apps (but not the others) saying that they [use permissions which are no longer allowed](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/providing-safe-and-secure-experience.html).  They email at the bottom specifically states the app ID and the permissions `READ_CALL_LOG, WRITE_CALL_LOG`

The problem is that none of my apps use these permissions.  None of the libraries I pull in use these permissions.  I have verified with `aapt l -a myApp.apk | grep CALL_LOG`, which gets no hits.

Is there any way some other permission would somehow include these permissions implicitly?  I'm worried this must be an error on the part of the Play store, as none of my other apps have been flagged?  Is there anything I might be overlooking?

If it helps, here is a listing of all the permissions in my manifest:

```
$ ./aapt l -a ~/myApp.apk | grep PERMISSION -i
      [snip some string resources...]
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.mycompany.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" (Raw: "com.mycompany.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")
    E: uses-permission (line=16)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.mycompany.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" (Raw: "com.mycompany.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")
    E: uses-permission (line=17)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
    E: uses-permission (line=18)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION")
    E: uses-permission (line=19)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
    E: uses-permission (line=20)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.VIBRATE" (Raw: "android.permission.VIBRATE")
    E: uses-permission (line=21)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" (Raw: "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
    E: uses-permission (line=22)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" (Raw: "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK")
    E: uses-permission (line=23)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" (Raw: "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE")
    E: uses-permission (line=24)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.CAMERA" (Raw: "android.permission.CAMERA")
    E: uses-permission (line=45)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" (Raw: "android.permission.BLUETOOTH")
    E: uses-permission (line=48)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" (Raw: "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN")
    E: uses-permission (line=51)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" (Raw: "android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED")
    E: uses-permission-sdk-23 (line=53)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION")
    E: uses-permission (line=55)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE")
        A: android:permission(0x01010006)="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" (Raw: "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND")
        A: android:grantUriPermissions(0x0101001b)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
        A: android:permission(0x01010006)="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION")
        A: android:permission(0x01010006)="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" (Raw: "android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES")
        A: android:permission(0x01010006)="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" (Raw: "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND")
```

Comment: If you grep for `targetSdkVersion`, what value do you get?

Comment: Great question - I'm targetting 26 in my gradle files, but aapt shows 'android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x16'. (22)  It is possible in this case I haven't rebuilt the app since updating gradle?

Comment: aapt isn't lying to you - the APK you provided targets 22.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I haven't updated this apk in Google Play yet.  However I'm still not using the called out permissions... could the targetSdkVersion be part of the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

**You must send a Declaration form to google for requesting permissions for our app**

[Google Declaration from](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfCnRaa4b1VuHhE4gVekWJc_V0Zt4XiTlsKsTipTlPg5ECA7Q/viewform)

Comment: Please reread the question - I'm not looking to use these permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all SMS & Call related permissions from the manifest file and then upload the latest build to Playstore.

After approval of app by Google playstore, the warning will be still there.

So , fill this declaration form.

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfCnRaa4b1VuHhE4gVekWJc_V0Zt4XiTlsKsTipTlPg5ECA7Q/viewform

After 24 hrs of submitting of this form , the warning will be removed from the playstore